# HDPE vs PP for storing pure aldehydes

Tags: polymers, reactivity, hydrocarbons, equipment, plastics

I know both HDPE and PP have at least some degree of resistance to aldehydes, esters and aliphatic hydrocarbons.

I am concerned however about minute contamination over time of pure samples and so I wonder how PP and HDPE compare to each other as to their resistance to aldehydes (mainly) as well as to the other two groups.

Comment: I am just guessing the isotactic PP should be somewhat more resistent to contamination penetration due tougher structure. But the surface adsortion though, it may be similar for both. The short-time contamination leading to adsorption may be the major problem, depending on the case.

Comment: General idea is storing organics ( especially nonpolar ) in glass and storing trace-contamination sensitive inorganics ( very dilute solutions for AAS) or glass attacking inorganics ( HF ) in HDPE/PP plastic. But you know that.

Comment: Plasticizers can migrate. Not all PP and HDPE are plasticizer-free.

Comment: DrMoishe Pippik: How does one know which plasticizers are used in a given PP/HDPE item? Is there any standard marking on this like an adjunct to the plastic type logo? I noticed sometimes there's a number inside the logo.